# Should [glitches] exist? There's 8 questions right now, but more would fit

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Should [glitches](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glitches) exist? There's 8 questions right now, but more would fit.

It has no Usage Guidance right now, so it doesn't seem official yet?

There's 28 questions mentioning "glitch" without having that tag...

https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/search?q=glitch+-%5Bglitches%5D

---

Then there's the older question of:

[Are questions about bugs in retro games on topic?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/825/)

Which ended with 4 total upvotes for Yes.

Comment: Related: https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/825/

Answer (score 1):

'Glitch' isn't a real term, but a placeholder for various symptoms/assumptions/impressions. Using this as a tag would make any search rather useless. If a real symptom/impression/etc is found, than this *may* be useful as tag, but 'glitch' should not.

Comment: *'Glitch' isn't a real term, but a placeholder for various symptoms/assumptions/impressions* — a.k.a. ‘it’s not a bug, it’s a feature’

Comment: @user3840170 spot on :)

Comment: More like [*"well, it worked when I tried it"*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/glitch) ?

Answer (score 1):

To me, *glitch* seems just a gaming-specific synonym for a software bug, especially one that:

- keeps the game running (this is probably the most important property);
- violates the intended game mechanics;
- results from a low-level problem such as overflow, race condition or memory corruption, as opposed to a logic error (e.g. sequence-breaking a puzzle);
- may require actions not usually performed in normal gameplay to be triggered;
- can be used to the player’s advantage.

Sometimes *glitch* is used in the meaning of ‘exploit’ instead, like in the expression *perform the glitch*.

Given that low-level bugs tend to happen more often in software written in low-level languages, and that includes most games considered ‘retro’, I figure there might be quite a lot of those that would fit within the scope of retrocomputing.

We don’t seem to have a tag for software bugs in general (not that there aren’t some questions for which one would fit, like [the one about Y2K](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15259/)), but if one existed, perhaps [glitches](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glitches) could be merged into it. But I can also see some value in keeping it separate.

**Later**: I have created [bugs](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) and applied it to a number of questions; in some, [glitches](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glitches) would have clearly been inappropriate.

Comment: Glitch as a term is older than game software. It was already used in electronics (debugging) in the 60s.

Comment: @Raffzahn yes, but with a very different meaning

Comment: I have long used, and still  use, 'glitch' as any sort of minor but irritating and probably not 100% repeatable bug in a computer system, in the hardware or software. I don't think my use is unusual, either.  If there is such a tag, it should not be construed as specific to game-playing.

Answer (score 1):

When I was growing up in the 90s, the books I read drew a distinction that a bug originated in software while a glitch originated in hardware.

(eg. bad connections like you'd get from [cartridge tilting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SP5c_MEs9mo), broken traces, failed capacitors, etc.)

If we want the tag to be meaningful, I'd go in that direction.

Comment: This is indeed the canonical distinction, according to Wreck-it Ralph.